# For classification w unbalanced datasets, is class-weighing the same as oversampling?

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, weighted-sampling, weighted-data

in unbalanced classification problems, I find myself using class_weigh = "auto" or similar parameters often, but I don't think I'm fully understanding what it's doing. I know that it's the industry practice to do so, but I don't have a deep understanding of it.

If we have an unbalanced 90/10 dataset, does giving 9 times more weight to the minority class mean the same thing as oversampling the minority class? Or is giving higher weight completely different from oversampling? (also - in the case of oversampling in this particular 90/10 example, would we want to be sampling from the minority class 9x the normal amount?)

If not, how do the ML algorithms take into account the heavier weight of the minority class? Is it automatically computed into the cost function they seek to minimize? Am I making any sense? (probably not, as I'm getting twisted myself).

Any input would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what approach did you choose for this?